# Size an image to full height or width depending on it's orientation?

Tags: html, css

I need to have a list of images, I do not know the size of the images, some could be landscape, some could be portrait.

The landscape ones should fit 100% width of parent li, the portrait ones should fit 100% height.

The only method I can get to work is working out if the image is landscape or portrait server side and adding a relevant class, which in turn would make width 100% or height 100%.

Is there a way to do this, maintaining aspect ratio, without using object fit or a background image?

Comment: Not that I know of. CSS can't detect *size* so it would have no way of determining wheher the image is landscape or portrait. That *is* what JS is for.

Answer (score 2):

Use `max-height` and `max-width` for images. You can also center them so small images will be looked fine.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  }
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  }
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/02/08/20/57/man-629062_960_720.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/08/15/21/man-1128277_960_720.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```